# Why is this JS Form Verification script not triggering?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I cannot figure out why my script is not triggering. I am trying to create form validation for this select element, requiring that is the `Other` option is chosen, then the following input field be set as `required`. As it is, the `other_lab` input field is not becoming `required` when `Other` is chosen in the select element. Here is the code:

```
<form id="form_1" method="post">
<label for="lab">Lab</label>        
<select id="lab" required name="lab">
    <option disabled selected value="">Choose lab</option>
    <option value="Lab_1">ABC</option>
    <option value="Lab_2">DEF</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<label for="other_lab">If other, please specify: </label>
<input name="other_lab" id="other_lab" size="15">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById('form_1');
  form.onsubmit = function (e){
    if(document.getElementById('lab').value == "Other") {
      document.getElementById('other_lab').setAttribute("required","");
    }else{
      document.getElementById('other_lab').removeAttribute("required","");
    }
  }   
</script>
```

Comment: I changed the code slightly to only contain `getElementById` methods. I do not think this other question is still pertinent.

Comment: I don't think it has any effect if `onsubmit` you add a `required`-attribute on any of the input elements. That is only going to affect the next submit.

Comment: @connexo You were correct, thank you! I changed the `onsubmit` method to an `addEventListener("input"...)` and my problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has any effect if `onsubmit` you add a `required`-attribute on any of the input elements. That is only going to affect the next submit.

Instead, if you want to make sure the form submit doesn't go through, use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

inside the condition that you need to prevent it on. This will cancel the submit, and the added `required` attributes can take effect on the next submit.

Comment: Okay, I changed `getElementsByTageName('form')` to `getElementById('form_1')`, and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById instead with the form id as a parameter, you used it with your other elements, why don't you use it with the form as well?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form_1');
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  alert('submit');
}
```

```html
<form id="form_1" method="post">
  <label>Lab</label>
  <select id="lab" required name="lab">
    <option disabled selected value="">Choose lab</option>
    <option value="Lab_1">ABC</option>
    <option value="Lab_2">DEF</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <label for="other_lab">If other, please specify: </label>
  <input name="other_lab" id="other_lab" size="15">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

document.getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList, not a single DOM node.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

notice the **s** in Elements which signals that it returns some form of collection.

I suggest you have a look at this page to learn about HTML forms:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Okay, I changed `getElementsByTageName('form')` to `getElementById('form_1')`, and the problem still exists.

Comment: Well you can execute my code by pressing "run code snippet", and find out that my code runs. I just replaced the body of your function with an alert to simplify things.

Comment: When I execute your code, the form is submitted regardless of the choices I choose. What I desire is for the input field to be required when the option `Other` is selected, and thus the form should not be able to be submitted. Otherwise, the form should be able to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by binding that same function on selectbox's change event.

Comment: A low-quality answer. Please consider explaining for future SO users.